# using mongodump with mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb

For some reason I cant connect to atlas using the connection string but instead of using mongo use mongodump. I have tried all type of string.

So its either I get "positional argument not allowed" when the I just replace mongo with mongodump 
or
 I get

> "failed: error connecting to db: no reachable servers" when I change
>   the host from
>   "mongo://replset1:27017,replset2:27017,replset3:271017/test?replicaSet=replicaSetName"
>   to --host replicaSetName/replset1:27017,replset:27017,replset3:27017

Anyone know what the problem is here.

Rememeber I can make connections using mongo client.

Comment: The Atlas dashboard where you see an overview of your clusters has three buttons Metric|Connect|... click ... and select command line tools, under Binary Import and Export tools there'll be a mongorestore and mongodb commands you need. Tweak to reference your local /bin folder and passwords.

Answer (score 67):

Currently mongoDB Atlas has a copy and paste option for "mongodump" in the "Command Line Tools" section of your cluster. First login to your mongoDB Atlas cluster. Next, on the left side of the screen make sure "Clusters" is chosen. Then, you'll see two options "Overview" and "Security", make sure "Overview" is chosen. Directly below "Overview" you should see "Sandbox". Under "Sandbox" you should see the name of your cluster which is a clickable link, click it. You'll then see a number of optional links to click, click "Command Line Tools". Here you'll see the copy and paste option for "mongodump".

Comment: This helped but now it is under Cluster -> Drop down select next to 'Collections' button -> Command Line Tools

Comment: you saved me!!! Nothing worked for me but this..

Answer (score 22):

If you have the srv string.
You can simply do `mongodump --uri=mongodb+srv://xxx:yyy@cluster0-whatever.mongodb.net`.
This seemed to just straight up work for me :)

Comment: Just make sure the username xxx is an Atlas Admin. otherwise you will get an error trying to read the admin database.

Answer (score 14):

In my case I finally got it this way:

`# mongodump -d DB-NAME -u SUPERUSER -p "SUPERUSER-PASSWORD" -o "PATH/TO/DUMP/FOLDER" --authenticationDatabase AUTH-DB --ssl --port 27017 -h "REPLICA-SET-NAME/CLUSTER-SHARD-00-00,CLUSTER-SHARD-00-01,CLUSTER-SHARD-00-02"`

Where:

- DB-NAME: Name of the database to backup
- SUPERUSER: User name with all privileges, the one you got creating the cluster
- SUPERUSER-PASSWORD: Self explanatory ;)
- PATH/TO/DUMP/FOLDER: Where you want to save the dump
- AUTH-DB: The database for authentication, by default is called "admin"
- REPLICA-SET-NAME: The name of the replica set in the form "cluster-name-shard-0"
- CLUSTER-SHARD: Name of the cluster shards IE: "cluster-name-shard-00-00-kb2rd.mongodb.net, cluster-name-shard-00-01-kb2rd.mongodb.net, cluster-name-shard-00-02-kb2rd.mongodb.net"

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you running? Thanks

Comment: Hi dworrad Version 3.4.10

Comment: Thanks! I tried to make it work for so many hours. I read in many places that I have to stop the replication before the dump, and I didn't want to do that, so I almost left it undone before I found this answer.
The weird thing is that I tried a very similar versions and I can't figure out why they didn't work. 
Too bad the errors are not helpful, and in some cases even misleading.

Comment: If you pass in the command with no -p/--password then you will be prompted for the password in your shell. Otherwise you are storing the password in your .bash_history or similar

Answer (score 12):

As of Feb 2021 with mongoDB v4.4; You can use

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@cluster-name.mongodb.net/<DATABASE>
```

N.B: If it does not work, try to omitting the database name.

Comment: I was getting "dumping up to 0 collections in parallel" error. Omitting the database name solved the issue and worked! Thank you!

Comment: You saved my day! I just omitted the DB name and now it's working :)

Answer (score 10):

As @charliecode mentioned, MongoDB Atlas actually shows you a proper way how to use mongodump/mongorestore/mongoexport/mongoimport. Visit your cluster in Atlas GUI, open **Command Line Tools** (hidden under more options), scroll down until you will see:

`mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://<username>:<PASSWORD>@made-up-url.5a45j.mongodb.net/<DATABASE>`

However I recommend a little change. Omit `<password>` in the URI because there is a good chance your password contains some special characters and it's both annoying and insecure to use non-encoded passwords directly in commands. mongodump will prompt you for the password afterwards.

`mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://<username>@made-up-url.5a45j.mongodb.net/<DATABASE>`

Painless.

Answer (score 5):

Every time when I dump my database from mongo atlas I use this command. Hope this helps. Happy coding... :)

```
mongodump -d $dbName -u $username -p $password \
-o . --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --port 27017 \
-h $hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error, but the following workaround has worked for me. It seems you can connect to a recent snapshot of your DB via Backup Tunnel. Basically what it does is it allows emulates MongoDB Server on a specified port. This implies you can make regular connection to it such as with 'mongodump'.

Link to official docs - https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/restore-queryable-backup/

Answer (score 0):

mongodump --host hostname --username username --password password --db databasename --out folderlocation

Answer (score 0):

mongodump --uri "your_atlas_connection_string"

Atlas connection string contains your user name, password, and database name.
You can choose your --out directory.

```
   Anil-iMac:bin anil$ ./mongodump --uri "mongodb+srv://USER_NAME:PASSWORD@mongoatlaslitehrm.0cfre.gcp.mongodb.net/YOUR_DB_NAME?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-m2x7xg-shard-0&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass%20Community&ssl=true" --out /Users/anil/Development/Personal/mongodb-database-tools-macos-x86_64-100.1.1/bin/bkup
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure Network access to Atlas cluster is proper. For taking a remote dump, add your instances IP to Atlas Ip access list.

```
sudo mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://admin:Anson_Alexander%40123@AAC-testing-cluster.ey913.mongodb.net/<NAME_OF_REQUIRED_DB>?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-rz#80g0-shard-0&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=true --out <LOCATION>
```