# MongoDB Atlas Sync to Local disk and archive

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodump, atlas

I have a MongoDB Atlas cloud database,
and I want to "sync" to a local server instance with `mongod` server running.

I have written an automated backup script that backs up a website, which then also does a `mongodump` to create an archive file from the (local) MongoDB, which then all gets dumped to an AWS bucket.

It's been working great, but I just realized that it's getting the local disk's mongo data, and not the "live" data on the Mongo Atlas cloud.

Is there a way `mongodump` can dump the MongoDB Atlas stuff to the local disk?

I hope there is an easier way than to "find" all on individual Atlas collections in my database, and "update" to the local disk.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653895/using-mongodump-with-mongodb-atlas

Answer (score 1):

I was successfully able to get a dump from Atlas to my local server using `mongodump`.

`mongodump --forceTableScan --url="mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@yourmongoserver.something.mongodb.net/<database name>"`

Note this failed until I included the `--forceTableScan`, which then after was seemingly successful.